# /etc/fstab - fuse-compatible alternative to nofail

Tags: fstab, fuse, unionfs

I want to join several external usb-disks with `mergerfs` to one large data-storage. Because the disks might not be available at all times I added the `nofail`-option, to prevent errors during boot.

This leads to the curious situation that everything works fine during boot, but I can't mount the disks later because `mount -a` fails with fuse complaining about the `nofail` option (`fuse: unknown option 'nofail'`). But I can't remove `nofail` either because this leads to an error during boot. So what are my alternatives? How do I do this right?

Im running. Debian 5.5.17-1~bpo10+1 (2020-04-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux

My current line in /etc/fstab:

```
/srv/dev-disk-by-label-EXTERN1:/srv/dev-disk-by-label-EXTERN2:/srv/dev-disk-by-label-EXTERN3            /srv/5d3c61b6-d6b0-42bd-9b48-2ef8632b12a3       fuse.mergerfs   defaults,nofail,allow_other,cache.files=off,use_ino,category.create=epmfs,minfreespace=10G,fsname=Storage_Extern:5d3c61b6-d6b0-42bd-9b48-2ef8632b12a3,x-systemd.requires=/srv/dev-disk-by-label-EXTERN1,x-systemd.requires=/srv/dev-disk-by-label-EXTERN2,x-systemd.requires=/srv/dev-disk-by-label-EXTERN3     0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

According to `man 8 mount` you could write your own *mount helper*, say `/sbin/mount.mynofail`, and replace type `fuse.mergerfs` in the fstab by `mynofail`.

On mounting, the script would be called with arguments corresponding to the fstab entry, minus various options. Your script would remove the fatal `"nofail,"` string from the options, and call `/sbin/mount.fuse` with the result, after appending `-t fuse.mergerfs`.